# C# exception handling under unit testing doesn't work

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, exception

I'm new in VisualStudio, so I haven't got much experience with the unit testing in it. 
I try to write a basic file reader class, wich has two variables: path and lines string list.

The path can be given to the constructor, or also can be set with a setter method.
There is a readIn function, which load up the list with the lines of the text file can be found on the path.
The function should chek if the path is not null or is it valid (is the path pointing to an existing file). If not, it throws a System.ArgumentNullException or a throw new System.ArgumentException.

When I try to test that the exceptions are thrown in case of the path is null or not valid, the VisualStudio always stuck and says that I have an unhadnled exception, however, I defined the expected exception before the test method.

Have you got any idea how should I do this in correct way? 
Or if it is the correct way (I read about it also here and on the msdn page too, so it should work), what should I do to get it work?

The reader class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace LogParserConsole
{
    public class FileReader
    {
        private string path;
        private List<string> lines;

        public FileReader()
        {
            path = null;
            lines = null;
        }

        public FileReader(string path)
        {
            this.path = path;
            if (isFileExists())
            {
                lines = new List<string>();
            }
            else
            {
                lines = null;
            }
        }

        public void readIn()
        {
            if(path == null)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("The path is not set. Please set a path first!");
            }
            else if(!isFileExists())
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException("The given path is invalid, please chek it!");
            }
            string line;
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }

            file.Close();
        }

        public bool isFileExists()
        {
            return File.Exists(path);
        }

        public string getPath()
        {
            return this.path;
        }

        public List<string> getLines()
        {
            return this.lines;
        }

        public void setPath(string path)
        {
            this.path = path;
        }
    }
}
```

The unit test method for the exception:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(System.ArgumentNullException))]
public void ReadInTest()
{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readIn();
}
```

I also tried an example from the msdn blog page about the expected exceptions (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csell/2006/01/14/expectedexception-might-not-be-what-youve-expected/), but it also stopped at the exception and after the test failed.
It happened with this simple example code:

```
[TestMethod, ExpectedException( typeof ( ApplicationException ) ) ]
public void ut1()
{
   throw new ApplicationException();
}
```

I think I should check my preferencies, but have no idea what should I search for.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I tried to reproduce what you explained, but NO! It works. So I cannot help you.

Comment: I guess, you're trying to **debug** your tests, not simply **run** them. In that case VS stops on unhandeled exceptions as with debugging any code. I believe, there is no way to change that behavior and, frankly speaking, I don't see any reason to do that.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is not the best name, but my first goal now is practicing.

Comment: It is still interesting to me, because if I start the test from the menu Test -> Run -> Run all Ctrl+R,A it runs correctly. And the hotkeys are pointing on that menu, so I think it should work the same way. But when I use the hotkeys, the tests are stopping at the exception.

Comment: I would guess that if you just hit F5, when the exception breaks, your test would pass. Try pressing CTRL+ALT+E in Visual Studio. Here you can control if exceptions should break when thrown or caught.

Comment: This question should be closed as no longer reproducible.

Comment: It is still reproducable. The problem still exist when I start the tests with the hotkeys. But only in that case. If I start them from the menu, works correctly. (I use the hotkeys shown in the menu, so I expected the same behaviour, but I haven't got that.)

Comment: For Michael: I think the test should work without I turn off the stop at exception option. And They works correctly, but just from the menu. Ok, maybe it should be closed, because it isn't a big issu, but very annoying to go to the menu every time, when I want to run my tests...

Comment: Mate this would only happen when you *debug* the test, as suggested by @EduardMalakhov. (whether with hotkeys or otherwise). this is the expected behaviour...

Comment: Yes, I already figured it out with the help of the comments, but I don't know how to close the question...